# App doesn't start with root. Can't find cause

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I am running a rooted Galaxy S20 with BeyondROM 6.3 and Magisk 27.0.
My banking app is working fine after I enabled hiding the Magisk app and adding my banking app to the deny list.

Now the problem is that I can't start the app from my health insurance and I just can't figure out why. It's [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.barmergek.serviceapp) app.

Every time I'm starting it I just get stuck on the loading screen and it's even so bad that my phone is frozen for some seconds.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my rooted device since they even say in the app infos on play store that you can't use it with a rooted app.

How can I get this thing to work?

Output from logcat for some seconds after starting the app:

https://file.io/f0b7aTrQqm6V

(had to upload it because the file is too long otherwise)

In Line `94` it starts with

```
02-17 18:56:40.593  7429  9046 I Pageboost: start alp : de.barmergek.serviceapp
```

and then in lines `119` & `120` we have:

```
02-17 18:56:40.620  7429  7522 I ActivityManager: Start proc 17694:de.barmergek.serviceapp/u0a383 for activelaunch {de.barmergek.serviceapp/de.barmer.serviceapp.viewlayer.activities.NativeSplashActivity}
02-17 18:56:40.626 17694 17694 I Magisk  : zygisk64: [de.barmergek.serviceapp] is on the denylist
```

which is the standard activity to start the app and the confirmation that the denylist is working.

Maybe line `193` can give some additional information:

```
02-17 18:56:40.680  7429 11408 D WindowManagerServiceExt:
notifyOccludeChangeNotice:
cn=ComponentInfo{de.barmergek.serviceapp/de.barmer.serviceapp.viewlayer.activities.NativeSplashActivity}
occludesParent=true inMultiWindow=false styleFloating=false
caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerServiceExt.updateOccludeTargetIfNeeded:1
com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.ensureActivitiesVisible:64
com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.ensureActivitiesVisible:36
com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.ensureActivitiesVisible:1
com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.completePause:246
```

Comment: Have you checked logcat for errors?

Comment: Does it not seem logical that the app info is saying that for a reason.  They have deliberately written it to detect if it is rooted.

Comment: @Robert unfortunately I don't really know how to do this, could you provide additional information on this?

Comment: @RohitGupta I mean the banking app is also normally not running if your device is rooted but i got it to work with the Magisk DenyList. So there maybe is also a possibility to get this app to work with root.

Comment: logcat is accessible via [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/). IMHO it is a basic requirement to work with Android in an advanced way.

Comment: okay so i got a log from logcat but there is a lot of unneeded stuff in there i think. I could use some filters as i can see in the `adb logcat --help` page but I don't really know what to filter for.
added the file in the original post

Comment: @Robert any idea on this matter?

Comment: Sorry, I can't you help on that topic. Barmer App is a "monster" of a React-Native app. Just the 64bit ARM Version has 100MB which means it has dozen of native .so libraries and an own JavaScript engine executing the whole react byte code. In my opinion the whole react native topic is just a waste of resources but developers love it as they can use JavaScript. Again something you can blame Facebook/Meta for...

Comment: @Robert okay thats a bummer... thanks for your support nonetheless!